# Models.Fitting type failure

Tags: julia

I've inherited some old code, which was written for a much earlier version of Julia (~v0.6). I'm running Julia 1.5.4 and I've already adjusted a lot of the existing code, without much trouble.

But when I run:

```
import Models
type GLMA <: Models.Fitting.AbstractFittingAlgorithm 
end
```

I get

```
ERROR: syntax: extra token "GLMA" after end of expression
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:1
```

Why is this happening?

(a) Is there an issue with the `type` part?

Additionally, (b) Why is `Models.Fitting` missing when I do this:

```
Models.Fitting
ERROR: UndefVarError: Fitting not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] getproperty(::Module, ::Symbol) at .\Base.jl:26
 [2] top-level scope at REPL[4]:1
```

Comment: Could it be that you have to define it as an `abstract type GLMA`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have to declare it as an abstract type rather than a "bare" type. For example:

```
import Models

abstract type GLMA <: Models.Fitting.AbstractFittingAlgorithm; end
```

I don't see any bare type references, just abstract and primitive:

- [Types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#man-types)
- [Abstract Types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#man-abstract-types)

So with the following I was able to reproduce your error message:

```
julia> abstract type X end

julia> type Y <: X end
ERROR: syntax: extra token "Y" after end of expression
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:1
```

Comment: Thanks, the ```abstract``` helps, but do you now what the problem is with ```Models.Fitting.AbstractFittingAlgorithm``` ?

Comment: @Mich55 Basically its saying that `Fitting` is not defined in the package, I wouldn't know whether it was because it was removed or because it was renamed. The only package named `Models.jl` I could find was the following: https://github.com/invenia/Models.jl And I didn't see any `Fitting` type or function defined

Comment: Is it possible that an old version of ```Models``` had ```Fitting.AbstractFittingAlgorithm```? If so, how can I look at older versions of the package?

Answer (score 1):

A remote possibility is that the old code brought Fitting into scope with import or using and the  keyword 'as' and if that renaming is not currently done, then you've lost that link.  More here:
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#Renaming-with-as